# Generic method to customize indentation?

Tags: indentation

Is there some method to customize indentation in various Emacs modes, possibly on a per-project level?

Projects can have widely different indentation styles, which can make automatic indentation inconvenient. For instance, one project may use a style

```
result = function(
    first_argument, second_argument,
    third_argument, fourth_argument)
....^ (four characterss)
```

while another with the same language may prefer

```
result = function(
        first_argument, second_argument,
        third_argument, fourth_argument)
........^ (eight characters)
```

for clearer distinction from code flow constructs, and another

```
result = function(first_argument, second_argument,
                  third_argument, fourth_argument)
..................^ (aligned with parentheses).
```

It seems, that how or whether both styles, or any other given style, can be supported by automatic indentation depends strongly on the language mode;

In Python-mode the first and third style are supported by default settings, but the second one would require customizing functions.

In Fortran, the first and second style are supported by changing customization variables, but the third would require writing a custom indent function. Instead of it, the builtin `f90-mode` would produce something like

```
result = function(first_argument, second_argument, &
        third_argument, fourth_argument)
........^ (customizable indent, but no option for aligning to parentheses)
```

More commonly, I resort to using manual indenting and `M-x indent-rigidly` (aka `C-x TAB`).

Is there any method to cleanly and reliably change indentation styles across modes?

Comment: In *general* the answer is "no", because modes are free to implement indentation however they choose, so there's nothing compelling them to align with other modes.

Comment: The [Editor Config](https://editorconfig.org/) project aims to provide support across modes (and across editors) for certain basic requirements (spaces/tabs, tab-width, etc), but I'm not sure it's useful for the more nuanced variations you're talking about.